# Creating a grid component in React - confused where to put state

Tags: reactjs

I'm a React novice. I'm building a generic grid component with a check column (similar to the Gmail inbox) so the user can easily select multiple rows (or all rows by clicking the checkbox in the header).

The Grid component is composed of a GridHeader and GridRows (composed of GridCells).

```
        <table className="grid">
            <GridHeader ... />
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

For each GridRow, I'm rendering a checkbox in the first column which toggles the "selected" state for that row.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked={selected} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

...

handleChange: function (event) {
    this.setState({selected: event.target.checked});
},
```

That works fine as far as updating the UI:

[image: current UI]

...but the user of this Grid component needs to somehow access the selected rows/records using an API call like this:

```
grid.getSelected()
```

It would be pretty inefficient if the getSelected() method had to iterate over every row to query its selected state.  So I was thinking of moving the selection state into the Grid's state. One concern I had was that now whenever the Grid's state.selected changes, it would cause the entire grid to be re-rendered.

Alternatively, the grid may keep an array of selected items in a variable separate from the state:

```
getSelected() { return this.selected } // array of selected row indices
```

And each individual row can still keep their own selected state so the UI can be updated, but this [may be an anti-pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) as now there's no longer one source of truth for the selection model.

Can someone guide me as to where to keep selection state for this grid?

Also, if I do need to iterate over the rows from within the grid component, must I attach a ref to each row and iterate over the refs?

I'm trying not to complicate this question too much, but keep in mind the grid needs to support a "select all" checkbox in the GridHeader which should select all rows in the grid (like in Gmail's inbox).

Comment: Perhaps some of my confusion is because I don't really know how components are intended to be used in a React application as I'm just getting started. I planned on structuring my app with simple controllers that would fetch data and handle component callbacks (i.e. a cell was clicked, load a record). The React tutorial component does not require a controller since it does its own Ajax call to fetch data it needs.

Comment: A slight update. The "React one-hour email" example here https://github.com/petehunt/react-one-hour-email is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. In that example, the selection is stored in the main grid-not in the individual rows. This does in fact cause all rows to be rendered on selection change. While this worked fine for 100 rows, increasing the rows to 1000 caused a large selection delay. However, the 'select all' requirement would need to render all rows anyway I suppose. In practice I will have smaller grids, so I suppose this will suffice. But I'm curious if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You are right in saying that changing the state "would cause the entire grid to be re-rendered", but it's not as expensive as you seem to think. The rendering happens to the _virtual DOM_, not the one rendered by the browser. The change to the real DOM would only be setting "selected" to true on the single checkbox. In general in React: don't think about rendering "performance" until it's actually a problem. Move the state up the hierarchy because that's where it belongs, and worry about perf if it becomes a problem.

Comment: @nogridbag: for a similar grid that I'm working on, I've put the state higher up still, so that the grid component itself just gets given the list of data and the list of selected item ids. The rows themselves just have a `selected` prop, which the grid render method sets based on whether the row of data is referenced in the selection. Then logic about select all, select unread, etc, is all outside the grid component too.

Comment: Thanks all for the advice. Douglas, that's actually how the "one-hour email" example works. The selection is stored in the 'App' and it's passed into a List via props.

Comment: I just want to note that it's best if the state is handled by the owner, meaning the grid. It's always best to have as little state management as possible, so anytime you can centralize the state management to one place, you're lowering complexity (even in non-react applications).

That said, @ssorallen gave an excellent answer and you should use his advice.

Comment: on the performance question for a large list (1000's +) as mentioned, its teh virtual dom, and that is fast. but you can also make it faster by adding a shouldComponentUpdate check inside your GridRow. Better still, do that in conjunction with an immutable data plugin (like this: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) and then you can use oldProps === newProps